# Multiple jQuery Sliding Content Boxes

Tags: jquery

jQuery beginner here.

I'm working on a site with with two links. Each link slides out content a div with content below. The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to toggle between both when the user clicks the other link.

So when the user clicks LINK-A it slides out CONTENT-A, while CONTENT-A is showing if the user clicks LINK-B CONTENT-A should slide back before CONTENT-B slides out.

Hope this makes sense, really hope someone can help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML--

```
<a href="#" id="link-a">Link A</a> - <a href="#" id="link-b">Link B</a>
<div id="container">
    <div id="content-a">Content A</div>
    <div id="content-b">Content B</div>
</div>
```

CSS--

Each `content` div is absolutely positioned inside of the `container` div so it can be animated in and out of view:

```
#container {
    position : relative;
    width    : 500px;
    height   : 200px;
}
#content-a {
    position   : absolute;
    top        : 0;
    left       : 0;
    width      : 100%;
    height     : 100%;
    background : red;
}
#content-b {
    position   : absolute;
    top        : 0;
    left       : -100%;
    width      : 100%;
    height     : 100%;
    background : green;
}
```

JS--

```
//cache the content area selectors since they will be used multiple times
var $content_a = $('#content-a'),
    $content_b = $('#content-b');

$('#link-a').on('click', function () {

    //when the `a` link is clicked, animate `b` content off-screen
    $content_b.stop().animate({
        left : '-100%'
    }, 500, function () {

        //then animate the `a` content on-screen after the `b` content's animation completes
        $content_a.stop().animate({
            left : 0
        }, 500);
    });
});

//then do the same (but in reverse) for the `b` link
$('#link-b').on('click', function () {
    $content_a.stop().animate({
        left : '-100%'
    }, 500, function () {
        $content_b.stop().animate({
            left : 0
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4eN84/

Comment: This is close, but the design I'm working on calls for content that is hidden below the nav. When a user clicks on a link the content slides down, if the content is down and the user clicks on the second link the first content slides up before the second slides down. I've thrown my current code into jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ninjarhino/4D3tv/). As it currently works, the sliding content can both show at the same time, which is a pain. Thanks for this!

Comment: @SimonMelhuish How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/4eN84/1/. I changed the left/right sliding for up/down using the `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()` functions.

Comment: Got exactly what I needed with a little tweaking thanks @Jasper! To allow users to close the boxes as I changed the slideUp and SlideDown to SlideUp and SlideToggle: http://jsfiddle.net/ninjarhino/4eN84/11/

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh-hah, without seeing your code I'm thinking you might find use in the .not selector.
http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

```
$("#foo .bar").not(this).hide();
```

This will basically grab anything BUT the thing you pass it, then do whatever to it (in this case hide). The nice thing about this is that doing it like so makes your UI expandable, if you plan to add more panels/windows later on.

Hopefully this gets you where you need to go. :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need a basic accordion set up.

HTML...

```
<a href="#sectA" class="slider">A header for content a</a>
<div id="sectA">Some content A here</div>

<a href="#sectB" class="slider">A header for content b</a>
<div id="sectB">Some content B here</div>
```

CSS...

```
.opened { display: block; }
div { display: none; height: 200px; background: #600; }
a { display: block; }
```

jQuery...

```
 $(".slider").click(function() {
            var dropD = $(this).attr("href");
            if ($("div#" + dropD + " .opened").length) { 
                $("div.opened").slideToggle(300).removeClass("opened");
            } else {
                $("div.opened").slideToggle(300).removeClass("opened");
                $("div#" + dropD).slideToggle(300).addClass("opened");
            }   
        return false;
        });
```

[jfiddle example HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/BMPZs/)

Answer (score 0):

Here, a nice solution:

[DEMO IN ACTION](http://jsbin.com/umitiw/edit#javascript,html,live)

**HTML:**

```
  <h2 class="button">Open 1</h2>
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>

  <h2 class="button">Open 2</h2>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div> 

  <h2 class="button">Open 3</h2>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
```

**jQ:**

```
$('.box').hide();

$('.button').click(function(){
  var box = $(this).next();
  box.is(':visible') ? box.slideToggle() : ($('.box').slideUp(), box.slideDown()); 
});
```

Just to explain the **ternary operators**:

`statement ? isTrue : isFalse ;`

As you can see, it toggles already opened boxes and also - hides the opened one if you click again on it!